# Divs get messed up when on lower resolution

Tags: html, css

I have added 2 screenshots below, to help understand my problem and what I'd like to achieve.

I have this layout: 
[image]

Now if I look at my page on lower resolution, it will try to rearange the divs on the left and right, ending up with them overlapping my middle div.

[image]

I'd like to set the page to scroll horizontally when on lower resolution so that this doesn't happen. I've tried setting the positioning to fixed and messing around with it, but it takes no effect or an even worse effect.

My HTML:

```
<div id="middle">

    <div id="next_event">
        <p class="no"><h4><u>Next event: 13.04</u></h4></p>
        <p class="no" style="font-size: 18px; text-align:left;"><span style="color: #0565a8;">Thema:</span> Sozialwissen
        <br><span style="color: #0565a8;">&nbspLocation:</span> Waehringer-Strasse 38, Wien
        <br><span style="color: #0565a8;">&nbspEintritt:</span> Freier Eintritt
        <br><span style="color: #0565a8;">&nbspGast:</span> Max Musterman
        <br><span style="color: #0565a8;">&nbspInfos:</span> 
        <a href="events.html" style="color: #333; text-decoration:none;"><u>Hier klicken</u></a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="team">
        <p class="no"><h4><u>Team</u></h4></p>
        <img src="img/photo.png" hspace="5" vspace="0">
        <img src="img/photo.png" hspace="5" vspace="5">
        <br>
        <img src="img/photo.png" hspace="5" vspace="5">
    </div>

    <div id="content"><p class="big">The thesis statement is that sentence or two in your text that ..</p><hr>
```

My CSS:

```
#middle
{
    overflow:visible;
}

#content
{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
    min-height: 800px;
    margin:100px auto 100px;
    width:800px;
    padding: 10px;
/*  border: 1px solid #373737;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #000000; */
    position:relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* background-color: white; */
    z-index:50;
    /* --- Add for scroll --- */
    /*  overflow: scroll;
        height: 700px;  */
}


#team
{
    position: fixed; 
    color: black; 
    left: 100;
    margin-top:20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #0565a8;
    text-align: center;
}

#next_event
{
    position:fixed; 
    color: black; 
    right: 100;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #0565a8;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: make it responsive using bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have figured it out. I only needed to change the width of all my middle divs to % instead of px. That means that my login, next_event and team id now have a width: 21%.

```
#team
{
    position: fixed; 
    color: black; 
    left: 100;
    margin-top:20px;
    width: 21%;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #0565a8;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Then there won be any scroll bar I guess

Answer (score 1):

Set all the container divs to fixed width, and add a `width` or `min-width` to `<body>` tag, and set the value equal/greater than the total width of all the container divs - **[quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/93qw9mbm/)**.

Edit, just realized that you use position fixed, be aware - **position an element "fixed" relatives to the window**, therefore, it's not possible to have the scroll bar working properly.

Comment: Aren't all my container divs fixed width already? Also adding a min-wdith to body doesn't change anything.

Comment: @BogdanLazar thanks for pointing that out, I updated the answer with more information, also check out this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/qx8zxwcd/ (it's not that easy).

Comment: Your edit and example is very helpful and I thank you for that. I will keep it in mind next time, when I'll need a scroll bar for the content.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the viewport technique?

in your head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
```

Then change your CSS sizes to %'s instead of pixels. This includes font sizes too.

[note: this will make the page view able on mobile, tablets, and PC]